# Soundtrack of The curious case of benjamin button

Tags: soundtrack

I am not able to find the soundtrack which is played in curious case of benjamin button movie,can any one suggest me where can i find that soundtrack

this is the scene

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/97/a1/f6/97a1f6b2b5cfee836c6c9ee5ce2a3749.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the soundtrack album on multiple services:

iTunes:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/curious-case-benjamin-button/id302662693

Amazon:
[http://www.amazon.com/Picture-Curious-Benjamin-Alexandre-2009-01-19/dp/B014I76WTS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1453640821&sr=8-1&keywords=Music+from+the+Motion+Picture+The+Curious+Case+of+Benjamin+Button](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014I76WTS)

Spotify: 
https://open.spotify.com/album/5vAQnavMQRIdr2kyAQJRi1